# Processing and storing the excel file in database as fast as possible

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have to process a huge Excel file and then save the data in a database. I need an advice because I am planning to use POI library for that, but my concern is: can I introduce multi-threading in it? Let's say if the Excel file is big enough can we break it in chunks and then process it? My objective is to process the file and store it in database as fast as possible.

Comment: .xls or .xlsx? If .xlsx then check the [Sax api](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api). Multithreading won't work  with that approach

Answer (score 0):

Using sax parser implementation provided by POI is helpful for low memory stack. I have tried with 3 million record with multi threading and was successful.